# How to make a function atomic in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, synchronization, interrupt

I'm currently writing an iOS app in Swift, and I encountered the following problem: I have an object A. The problem is that while there is only one thread for the app (I didn't create separate threads), object A gets modified when
1) a certain NSTimer() triggers
2) a certain observeValueForKeyPath() triggers
3) a certain callback from Parse triggers.

From what I know, all the above three cases work kind of like a software interrupt. So as the code run, if NSTimer()/observeValueForKeyPath()/callback from Parse happens, current code gets interrupted and jumps to corresponding code. This is not a race condition (since just one thread), and I don't think something like this https://gist.github.com/Kaelten/7914a8128eca45f081b3 can solve this problem.

There is a specific function B called in all three cases to modify object A, so I'm thinking if I can make this function B atomic, then this problem is solved. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making some incorrect assumptions. None of the things you mention interrupt the processor. 1 and 2 both operate synchronously. The timer won't fire or observeValueForKeyPath won't be called until your code finishes and your app services the event loop.

Atomic properties or other synchronization techniques are only meaningful for concurrent (multi-threaded) code. If memory serves, Atomic is only for properties, not other methods/functions.

I believe Parse uses completion blocks that are run on a background thread, in which case your #3 **is* using separate threads, even though you didn't realize that you were doing so. This is the only case in which you need to be worried about synchronization. In that case the simplest thing is to simply bracket your completion block code inside a call to dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()), which makes all the code in the dispatch_async closure run on the main, avoiding concurrency issues entirely.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You said that "The timer won't fire or observeValueForKeyPath won't be called until your code finishes and your app services the event loop". At what time is the code considered to be finished? For instance inside observeValueForKeyPath() there will ten lines of code including some function calls that modify object A. Do you mean the NSTimer() or the next observeValueForKeyPath() will not trigger until these ten lines of code finished running?

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention a fourth case which will modify object A - in the function locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion). While I'm inside the function locationManager(), NSTimer or observeValueForKeyPath also won't kick off until I finished executing the whole locationManager() function?

Comment: I just have another question about using dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()). As far as I know, this will causes my code to run asynchronously on the main thread. However, how can this avoid concurrency issue? Also, if I do this, will UI hang while the Parse code tries to fetch data from Parse server?

Comment: that is, shouldn't I be using dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) instead so UI won't hang? But if I do this, then again there is synchronization problem

Comment: NO. You want `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())`. The function `dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)` returns a queue that runs on a **BACKGROUND** thread, which is exactly what you do not want.

Comment: You must never make UIKit calls on a background thread. It causes all sorts of problems.

Comment: I see. So where exactly should I add dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())? My Parse call is findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock(). Should I beed adding the dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) within "if error == nil {}" (i.e. when Parse callback happens)

Comment: You can wrap all the code you call in your `findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock` block in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` if you want. That's certainly easy. However, if you have time-consuming work you need to do on the data you get back, then you might want to do that time-consuming work outside of your call to `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())`, and then only put the code that does UIKit calls inside a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` block.

Comment: I think what confuses me is that you keep mentioning UIKit. But then I'm not actually updating any UI. In findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock()'s callback, I will update a Double array, which must be synchronized (but it has nothing to do with UI). This is why I don't understand why you are suggesting to use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()). If I didn't get what you mean correctly, please correct me.

Comment: findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock() is an asynchronous call. It has to be an asynchronous call because I don't want it to block the thread which results in UI hanging. If I put findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock() into main queue, doesn't that basically make my asynchronous function synchronous? And this will cause UI to hang?

Comment: No, you misunderstand. The method `findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock` runs asynchronously (and presumably on a background thread, although this is hidden from you.) Then, once it's done, it invokes the block you give it, on a background thread. (This is after the slow network read is done.) You can run computation code directly (on a background thread) in the completion block. However, if you need to install output into the UI, you need to wrap the UI code in calls to dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()).

Comment: If the work you need to do in your completion block is quick, you can wrap the entire body of the completion block in a dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) call, so all the code runs on the main thread. That doesn't make the work done in `findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock` synchronous.